# MyBB backup (sql.gz) import to Phpmyadmin error

Tags: database, mybb

recently I downloaded a backup for my MyBB forum, which is in a .sql.gz file, now I've tried to import this towards Phpmyadmin but this did not work out. (Error on line one due a question mark). How can I import this backup?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you downloaded the backup from your phpMyAdmin itself or from mybb Admin panel ?

Comment: Admin panel @ksreddy